# Does Windows (7) impose a limit to size of drag and drop data?

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

I am using a program, ProRealTime, that has some data which can be drag and dropped to other programs, such as Notepad++, Open Office Writer etc. I do not get all the data though, and thinking that it was ProRealTime that capped the amount of data being drag and dropped I sent them an email asking them about it. The response I got back was

*"I just checked with our programmers - and they say that it's actually the limit imposed by windows. From our side, you are supposed to have more than 1000 trades."*

I found that... surprising, given that it is not a lot of data (pure text, file size usually is about 70 KB) and I have not encountered any sort of cap like this earlier. I have been trying to find more information about this limitation set by Windows but cannot find anything. Does such a "restriction" exist or are they wrong / lying? If such a restriction exist, can something be done about it?

Comment: Ask them to provide a Microsoft link to back up what they say. As far as I know there is no Windows limitation.

Comment: Related question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873918/maximum-size-of-qmimedata-windows-drag-and-drop-vs-clipboard

Comment: I have dragged an dropped over 500gb of data before without issue in W7

Comment: I have dragged and dropped 1.5 TB Acronis True Image archive files to different storage locations.  The response is complete rubbish, the behavior in this program, is entirely up to them to implement.  The type of control they are suing does not have this functionality out of the gate, I guarantee it, so their implementation is to blame.

Comment: He's not talking about moving data around. He's using the open with feature that kicks in when dragging and dropping a file onto another one. if you drag and drop a txt file on to word or excel icon, it will launch the app and open the file. with that being said it sounds like some sort of parsing error when the application is opening the data. Does it work if you go file > open and do it that way?

Comment: @acme64 The data cannot be saved to a file from within PRT, it has to be dragged into another application and then saved. I get the same result whether I'm dragging it to Notepad++ or Open Office Writer.